# How do I get my Try statements not throw errors

Tags: python-2.7, exception, try-catch

I am trying to execute some statements within Try block. I am calling an API and performing some operations. There is one specific operation which is resulting in RuntimeError which is puked while running the program, although I am catching it with an exception. How do I go about avoiding the errors being puked from Try block?

```
try:
    call API and perform some tasks.
    encounters an error here
Except RunTimeError as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well as Susmit R. Veena said the point of try and except is to catch the error thrown in the try block.

In case you have some flow you want to ignore from its exceptions in the try block, than you can have a nested try catch block for the specific error you want to ignore and keep doing the logic after it is ignored.

for example:

```
try:
   try:
       call API and perform some tasks.
       encounters an error here
   Except TheErrorYouWantToIngore:
       pass

   keep on doing some stuff even TheErrorYouWantToIngore has been throwed

Except RunTimeError as ex:
   print(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

the whole point of try and except is to catch the errors thrown by the code in try block in except block. Post the code for solution to the error